Serverless Offline is using the environment variables from actual AWS SSM instead of local .env file
I have a Nest JS Lambda backend and I am using serverless-offline module to run it locally and connect to my local Postgres database.
My serverless.yml file looks like
service: wbx-borrower-onboarding-service
frameworkVersion: '3'

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-plugin-log-retention
  - serverless-prune-plugin
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin

package: 
  individually: true

custom:
  stage: ${opt:stage}
  region: ${env:REGION, 'ap-south-1'}
  accountId: ${aws:accountId}
  prune:
    automatic: true
    number: 5
  logRetentionPeriod:
    dev: 14
    prod: 90

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: ${opt:region, 'ap-south-1'}
  timeout: 30
  apiGateway:
    binaryMediaTypes:
      - "multipart/form-data"
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: ${self:provider.stage}
    CLERK_API_KEY: ${ssm:/wbx/${self:provider.stage}/clerk/secret/key}
    WBX_BORROWER_ONBOARDING_DOCS_S3_BUCKET: wbx-borrower-onboarding-docs
    WBX_DB_PROXY: ${ssm:/wbx/${self:provider.stage}/db/proxy}
    WBX_DB_HOST: ${ssm:/wbx/${self:provider.stage}/db/host}
    WBX_DB_USER: ${ssm:/wbx/${self:provider.stage}/db/user}
    WBX_DB_PASSWORD: ${ssm:/wbx/${self:provider.stage}/db/password}
    WBX_DB_NAME: woodbox

functions:
  <FUNCTION>

My local .env file looks like
WBX_DB_PROXY=localhost
WBX_DB_HOST=localhost
WBX_DB_USER=postgres
WBX_DB_PASSWORD=mydbpwd
WBX_DB_NAME=mydb
WBX_BORROWER_ONBOARDING_DOCS_S3_BUCKET=my-bucket
CLERK_API_KEY=api-key
FAKE_VAR=hellohello

My app.module.ts looks like
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import pg from 'pg';
import { SequelizeModule } from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { OnboardingModule } from './onboarding/onboarding.module';
import { Borrower } from './models/index';

@Module({
  imports: [
    SequelizeModule.forRoot({
      dialect: 'postgres',
      dialectModule: pg,
      host: process.env.WBX_DB_PROXY,
      port: 5432,
      username: process.env.WBX_DB_USER,
      password: process.env.WBX_DB_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.WBX_DB_NAME,
      models: [Borrower],
    }),
    OnboardingModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}


When I run sls offline start --reloadHandler --stage dev it prints the following on the terminal
DOTENV: Loading environment variables from .env:
         - WBX_DB_PROXY
         - WBX_DB_HOST
         - WBX_DB_USER
         - WBX_DB_PASSWORD
         - WBX_DB_NAME
         - WBX_BORROWER_ONBOARDING_DOCS_S3_BUCKET
         - CLERK_API_KEY
         - FAKE_VAR
Starting Offline at stage dev (ap-south-1)

which means it is reading the local .env file but then when the control reaches the app.module.ts it is somehow reading the actual ssm parameters I have configured on my AWS account. I know this because when I print console.log(process.env.WBX_DB_HOST); in my service it returns the actual RDS endpoint instead of the localhost as given in the local .env
I even tried installing the dotenv plugin separately and calling it in the app.module.ts and then in main.ts but it still did not help

You can provide environment value based on a condition (ex: stage). Then, when the stage is dev let provide an empty object, otherwise provide env value from SSM.
service: wbx-borrower-onboarding-service
frameworkVersion: '3'

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin

package: 
  individually: true

custom:
  stage: ${opt:stage}
  region: ${env:REGION, 'ap-south-1'}
  accountId: ${aws:accountId}
  prune:
    automatic: true
    number: 5
  logRetentionPeriod:
    dev: 14
    prod: 90
  environment: # Define env object for 2 stages
    prod:
      NODE_ENV: ${self:provider.stage}
      CLERK_API_KEY: ${ssm:/wbx/${self:provider.stage}/clerk/secret/key}
      WBX_BORROWER_ONBOARDING_DOCS_S3_BUCKET: wbx-borrower-onboarding-docs
      WBX_DB_PROXY: ${ssm:/wbx/${self:provider.stage}/db/proxy}
      WBX_DB_HOST: ${ssm:/wbx/${self:provider.stage}/db/host}
      WBX_DB_USER: ${ssm:/wbx/${self:provider.stage}/db/user}
      WBX_DB_PASSWORD: ${ssm:/wbx/${self:provider.stage}/db/password}
      WBX_DB_NAME: woodbox
    dev: {} # Empty
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: ${opt:region, 'ap-south-1'}
  timeout: 30
  apiGateway:
    binaryMediaTypes:
      - "multipart/form-data"
  environment: ${self:custom.environment.${opt:stage}} # Select env object based on the stage

